# Insertar un carácter en una cadena de texto en C

Tags: c

Bueno la cosa aquí es que el usuario me ingrese una cadena de texto y seguidamente me de un número que será la posición dentro de la cadena donde se insertara en este caso un "@". La cosa en que si el usuario pone como cadena "holamundo" y da como posición un "6" el resultado termina siendo: "holam@undo@" esto la verdad es que no se el porque además de que hay otros errores parecidos.
Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

int main() {
    char c[MAX],t[MAX];
    int u, i, m;
    printf("Escriba una cadena (su tamaño no ha de superar los 99 caracteres)");
    gets(c);
    m = strlen(c);
    if(m>99){
        printf("\nEl largo de la cadena ha resultado ser demasiado grande");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nDame la ubicacion en la cadena donde se insertara '@' (no dar una ubicacion que supere a la cadena)");
    scanf("\n%i",&u);
    if(u>m){
        printf("\nLa ubicacion dada ha superado el largo de la cadena de la cadena");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(t,c);
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        if(i>=u-1){
            c[i+1]=t[i];
        }
    }
    c[u-1] = '@';
    printf("\n\t%s\n", c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

¡hola Juan!
al parecer tienes problemas con tu compilador, te recomiendo que lo instales y desistales, no le hize grandes modificaciones a tu codigo y funciona perfectamente
te mando captura de ejecución
¡saludos!

[image: Ejecución]

```
int main() {
char c[MAX],t[MAX];
int u, i, m;
printf("Escriba una cadena (su tamaño no ha de superar los 99 caracteres)");
gets(c);
m = strlen(c);
if(m>99){
    printf("\nEl largo de la cadena ha resultado ser demasiado grande");
    exit(1);
}
printf("\nDame la ubicacion en la cadena donde se insertara '@' (no dar una ubicacion que supere a la cadena)");
scanf("\n%i",&u);
if(u>m){
    printf("\nLa ubicacion dada ha superado el largo de la cadena de la cadena");
    exit(1);
}
strcpy(t,c);
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    if(i>=u-1){
        c[i+1]=t[i];
    }
}
c[u-1] = '@';
printf("\n\t%s\n", c);
```

}

Comment: Saludos @CeballosRicardoFernando, tal vez lo mejor en este caso hubiera sido preguntar a OP cual es el error que le muestra el compilador, para así poder dar una respuesta más precisa, obviamente para preguntar debes escribir un comentario y no así una respuesta, te invito a leer [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así obtener tu primera medalla. ;)